# Cross platform rich text editor for react

Tags: web-apps, text-editor, react

I am trying to integrate a text editor for my web application. I tried both slatejs and draftjs, but both seem to be buggy on android browser, due to the way android keyboards handle `contentState`. This problem doesn't seem to have found a solution yet.

So my question is what is a good react text editor that works well and can be modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Draft js. it is by facebook.
https://draftjs.org/

Comment: Yeah, draftjs is very buggy with  android devices..

Comment: what about https://quilljs.com/

Comment: It seems to work fine. Although not very customizable. Thanks for the help